# Nodejs proper mapping with array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know why i cant get all data of subject that relate from student, The only data that display on response is the last id of student model, I tried to put **console.log(subject)** and i get the desired result but i dont know why i cant display it on response

```
const results = {
     student: null,
     subject: null,
}
const student = await StudentModel.getById(id)
if(student){
   for(let i = 0; i<=student.length - 1; i++){
     subject=  await SubjectModel.getByStudentId(student[i]._id)
     console.log(subject)
     subject.append(subject)
     
   }
}
results.subject= subject
res.json(data)
```

current result

```
student:[
   {
      id: 1,
      description: student 1
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      description: student 2
   }
],
subject:[
   {
      studentid: 2,
      description: subject 2
   }
]
```

desired result

result

```
student:[
   {
      id: 1,
      description: student 1
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      description: student 2
   }
],
subject:[
   {
      studentid: 1,
      description: subject 1
   },
   {
      studentid: 2,
      description: subject 2
   }
]
```

Update when I tried to implement append i received this error

***error: uncaughtException: subject.append is not a function***

Comment: If there are multiple `subject`s you need to append the subject; you're currently replacing the `subject` on each iteration.

Comment: what do you mean append?

Comment: like push? @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dave in the comments, you are not appending the values instead overriding it. You should do something like:

```
// If students is a list
const students = await StudentModel.getById(id); 
const subjects = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= students.length - 1; i++) {
    const subject = await SubjectModel.getByStudentId(students[i]._id)
    console.log(subject);
    subjects.push(subject);
}

const data = {
    students, subjects
}

res.json(data);
```

The code above will work fine, but as per my understanding if you are searching by id, there should not be more than one record, so your `getById()` function should give you the record or null if the record doesn't exist. If this is the case you might not even need a loop. All you can do is:

```
// If students is an object
const student = await StudentModel.getById(id);
const subject = student ? await SubjectModel.getByStudentId(student._id) : null;

const data = {
    students, subjects
}

res.json(data);
```